# Confusion with HTML Regex Pattern

Tags: html, regex

I have this pattern in HTML:

```
(\d{4}([\-]\d{4})?)
```

How can I change it to include letters and numbers, not only numbers?

The pattern should be `xxxx-xxxx` (including letters and numbers).

Comment: A cursory search of Google for REGEX syntax would solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `([0-9a-zA-Z]{4}[-][0-9a-zA-Z]{4})` to match `xxxx-xxxx` pattern.

If you want `-xxxx` to be optional (like it is in the pattern you wrote in the question), use - `([0-9a-zA-Z]{4}([-][0-9a-zA-Z]{4})?)`.

In case you want to include symbols except digits and alphabets, include them inside `[]` in the pattern. Ex: To include unserscore (`_`) use `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`

Answer (score 0):

Use

`[a-z0-9]`

which will match both, rather than

`\d`

which matches only numbers.